# Sintax of dict comprehension with some similar keys

Tags: python, python-2.7

It confused me that when I try to have a dict comprehension with some similar keys inside, python parse it sequentially and associate value with the last key.

It is obviously that hash table is been filled sequentially and each time when interpreter meets the same key it rewrite field in hash table.

```
In [15]: d = {1:2, 1:3, 1:4}

In [16]: d
Out[16]: {1: 4}
```

Here is a disasembled code:

```
In [10]: def foo():
    ...:     a = {1:2, 1:3, 1:4}
    ...:     

In [11]: dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 BUILD_MAP                3
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
              9 STORE_MAP           
             10 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
             13 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             16 STORE_MAP           
             17 LOAD_CONST               4 (4)
             20 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             23 STORE_MAP           
             24 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
             27 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             30 RETURN_VALUE
```

I expected that I should get a message with an error, for example "wrong/non-format input etc.", but actually I get a reduced dict. It is right and obvious, but a little confused because of it's sintax.
Could it be a point to write to Python community?

Comment: Is your post a question, or an affirmation? The argument that a dict definition where the same key is used multiple times should cause an error at runtime rather than taking the last value is defensible, but arguing about it is not what SO is for.

Comment: @Leporello, it is a question about format of code, that could cause a problems for those who do not know the hash table base of dicts. Python interprets such kind of dicts right, but it could be not obvious why Python 'eats' expressions with such 'strange/wrong/non-logical' format

Comment: If a tutorial fails to explain that Python dictionaries match one value to each key, take it up with whoever wrote it, not stackoverflow. If defining the same key multiple times should cause an error, take it with Python devs, not stackoverflow. If someone thinks that Python dictionaries match multiple values to the same key, take it with them, not stackoverflow. What do you expect *us* to help with?

Comment: In the way you wrote it in the example it almost makes sense what you are saying. But in your question you wrote about dict comprehension, and in that case raising an error will lose all the point of dictionaries. This is part of their functionality, to be able to overwrite old value with new. If this conflicts with what you expect it to do, simply don't use them because this is what they are for...

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't be a point to write this to the community as this is the expected behaviour of a dictionary. If you go to the dictionary [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), you'd see this line -

> If you store using a key that is already in use, the old value associated with that key is forgotten

Therefore, this is how dictionaries are intended to work.

Comment: Yes, I agree totally
But question was about format of code. It could cause a problems for those who do not know the hash table base of dicts

Comment: @GolovDanil That is not such a strong argument as they are welcome to go the docs and read about the objects they are using.

Comment: Oh you meant the syntax. Please edit your question as code is a confusing word, use syntax @GolovDanil

Comment: @Tomerikoo a lot of questions asked on SO can be solved by going through the docs IMO

Comment: Yes of course,I was trying to find an analogy for that dict case. What I meant is that the argument of that syntax being confusing to someone who doesn't know how dicts are implemented is not so strong in a way that you can't be surprised when things don't work how you expect if you don't know how they work... Am I being clear? I mean using a dict as `{1: 2, 1: 3, 1: 4}` without knowing that dicts are for unique keys... you're probably missing something basic

Comment: I'm downvoting this because I believe this type of question does not belong here on StackOverflow (and this answer isn't any more helpful than a comment).